# Sub nyquist sampling, required number of samples for time sparse grouped signals

Tags: sampling, nyquist, compressive-sensing, compression

Question: Does it make sense to perform compressed sampling if the non zero samples are grouped in time? If so, what is the minimal length of the vector x that should be acquired to allow full signal reconstruction (of at least the non zero pulse segments)?

$y=\phi x$, where y is the compressed vector and x is the signal (sampled at nyquist)

Situation: time sparse signal (+- 97 % of the samples at noise level), but the 3% non zero samples are grouped (periodic). I'm only interested in the pulse samples (so not in the noise floor samples). 
[image: a pulse train]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's something called *block sparsity* in compressed sensing literature which may be relevant to your question.

Comment: now is that an analog signal?  or is it already sampled and you're gonna downsample it or reduce the data?

Comment: Usually for time series like signals the idea is building the efficient dictionary and the location will be determined by the vector. Wouldn't that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

In original definition of Compressed sensing [1] it does not assume any distribution of non-zero elements in the input vector (signal), so it makes no difference if your non-zero elements are near each other or located uniformly on the sampling grid. The number of measurement, as theory states for all sparse signals, depends on how many non-zero elements you have (sparsity degree), what is your noise in input and what recovery quality your need (exact or approximation) and etc.
therefore,

> Does it make sense to perform compressed sampling if the non zero samples are grouped in time?

Yes!

I suggest the following video lecture of Baranuik:
[Video Lecture On CS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvMgVv-xZhQ)

Furthermore, for model-based compressive sensing you may read [3].

[1]: Donoho, David L. "Compressed sensing." IEEE Transactions on
information theory 52, no. 4 (2006): 1289-1306.

[3]: Baraniuk, Richard G., Volkan Cevher, Marco F. Duarte, and Chinmay
Hegde. "Model-based compressive sensing." IEEE Transactions on
information theory 56, no. 4 (2010): 1982-2001.

Comment: In many cases you can build equivalent MAP model for many CS models. So you can actually built a probabilistic interpretation.

Comment: Is not that called "model-based" compressive sensing??

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. But for instance, if you solve the classic $ {L}_{1} $ norm regularized Least Squares, which is a CS model, you actually solve a MAP problem with Laplace distribution prior. Moreover, the idea of sparsity is with relation to some basis / dictionary and not the non zero values of the signal.

Comment: @Royi at this point I do not even know myself what I meant back then :D, but I guess I was referring to concept that says if you basically know how the "non-zero" elements populate the search space you can converge faster.